# Wordpress Permalink Structure Not Updating

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I was working on a wordpress site, the client didn't own a domain so I set up a subdomain like so `wordpress.example.com` (note I used my own domain, not example), once the client had purchased a domain I moved the files to the right place and updated the permalink structure. The wordpress general settings look like so:

`Wordpress Address: http://clientdomain.com/
 Site Address: http://clientdomain.com/`

The permalink strucutre is also correct:

`Common Settings: 
//Unselected permalink settings
Post Name (•) : http://clientdomain.com/sample-post/`

And when I select any random blog post it says:

`Permalink: http://clientdomain.com/blog-post-name/`

However on the live version of the site clicking on any given blog post still tries to redirect me to `wordpress.example.com/blog-post-name`

Is it just a case of waiting for the changes to ripple through the system or have I missed something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: If you can access `http://clientdomain.com/` then your client domain is working. So I think you need to check into your code, If you have put any static URL in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WP stores post URL's in DB. You need to check post table and other tables too. Replace them with your live domain.

Comment: I initially changed them in DB, editing the URL in wp_options table, when this didn't work I used the second method (editing functions.php) as described here [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL), which updated the URLs in permalink settings to point to the right place, however the blog posts on the live site still link to the old domain. I just had a browse at every other table using Phpmyadmin and can't see anywhere else that requires the domain. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: My bad, just seen that each post has a GUID which is pointing to the incorrect place. Is there a more stable fix than writing an SQL query to update all of these posts? Not that SQL is unstable, just I'm a under confident in my SQL skills, or at least, I'm not particularly comfortable with editing all the posts directly in the DB